# Array treatment after a form submit with name[]

Tags: php, jquery

Actually I have a form like this:

```
<form>
    <input name="name[]">
    <input name="name[]">
</form>
```

That's fantastic because with `$(this).serialize()` I can get al the values into an array.

---

But today, I have a row with 2 inputs like this.

```
<form>
    <input name="name[]">  <input name="firstname[]">
    <input name="name[]">  <input name="firstname[]">
</form>
```

How can I treat the final array to match the input with the good value ?
For example I want `name[1]` goes with `firstname[1]`.

Thanks.

Comment: _I want name[1] goes with firstname[1]_ what do you mean by goes with? Do you want an array of string containing name and first name?

Comment: With those inputs `name[1]` will be matched with `firstname[1]`.

Comment: I do not want 2 different arrays but only one array of array.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what, you'll need a multidimensional array, so one of these two will give you one array:

```
<input name="data[name][]">  <input name="data[firstname][]">
<input name="data[name][]">  <input name="data[firstname][]">
```

Yields in `$_POST` array:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => something
                    [1] => something 2
                )

            [firstnamename] => Array
                (
                    [0] => something else
                    [1] => something else 2
                )
        )
)
```

Or, with this you will need to manually match the integer keys as `[]` will increment each time and not match the two values:

```
<input name="data[0][name]">  <input name="data[0][firstname]">
<input name="data[1][name]">  <input name="data[1][firstname]">
```

Yields in `$_POST` array:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => something
                    [firstnamename] => something else
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => something 2
                    [firstnamename] => something else 2
                )
        )
)
```